# is neithr pronoun or determiner

Tags: pronouns, determiners

Is *neither* pronoun or determiner in this sentence? (its exemplified as pronoun, but is it replaceable by noun phrase?)

neither of the boys sent in his report.

Official Guide to the Toefl Ibt Educational Testing Service-Official Guide to the TOEFL Test 4th Edition-McGraw-Hill (2012)

Comment: Well, it [depends on definitions...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun#Theoretical_considerations)

Comment: It's not a binary choice. Determiners often act as pronouns; some can stand alone and others can't.

Comment: Thanks. What do yo think about the the case in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there are two boys in question:

> Neither boy sent in his report.
>   Both boys sent in their reports.

The subjects of these sentences contain nouns with modifiers.   In these sentences, "neither" modifies "boy" and "both" modifies "boys".   Calling "neither" and "both" *determiners* in this usage seems quite reasonable.

> Neither sent in his report.
>   Both sent in their reports.

The subjects of these sentences don't contain any nouns.   The word "boy" doesn't appear in any form.   Instead, the adjectives on their own do the same job that a noun typically does.   Calling "neither" and "both" *pronouns* in this usage seems quite reasonable.

> Neither of the boys sent in his report.
>   Both of the boys sent in their reports.

The subjects of these sentences contain prepositional phrases, which act as modifiers.   Here, the phrases modify pronouns in the same way that they could modify noun phrases.

Finding noun phrases that carries the same meaning as the pronouns "neither" or "both" might not be possible.   Finding noun phrases that serve the same grammatical function is trivial.   Assuming that there are more than two boys in question:

> A couple of the boys sent in their reports.
>   One team of the boys sent in their reports.
>   A representative of the boys sent in his report.

Comment: Thank you very much, bit I didn't understand the last part of your answer. Can we say if "neither" in the sentence is a pronoun or not?

Comment: I have a similar question. Why "one" is determiner in the first sentence and pronoun in second? 1.One of my friends lives in Brighton. 2.It's a present for one of my children. (From OALD, "one" entry)

Comment: I found the first example under an entry that didn't mention any part of speech.  I didn't find the second example.  One of the boys, one of my friends, one of my children -- as I view them, those all use "one" as a pronoun.