Difference between a determiner and a pronoun?
What I learnt -
Can someone please clarify if the words in bold are determiners or pronouns?

Each of my teachers has long hair.
Both of my close friends live in Scotland.
Either of these plans sounds good.
Neither of these videos explains the procedure in detail..

What I learnt - How to identify distributive determiners

There is always a noun next to the distributive determiner. There is never a noun after the Distributive Pronoun. It means there may be any other word other than a noun.)
A distributive pronoun shall be followed by a plural noun, but if there is a distributive adjective, it will have a singular noun.

But the Cambridge dictionary says that 'either' is a determiner in the below sentences:


Either of the children can come with us; we don’t mind which.
I don’t want either of my parents to know I’ve lost my job.


Which is the correct way to identify a distributive determiner?
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/either

I'm not familiar with the terms distributive pronoun and distributive adjective, but I understand each, both, either, neither as distributive determiners. Is there any reason why all your examples feature of the [full set plural] rather than just each teacher, both close friends, either plan, neither video? And what practical difference would it make to you how the word either is categorized in your final two examples? Is this just a question about "labels", or is there some context where if makes a difference to how something is expressed in English?

It is of academic interest and also helpful for those preparing for the competitive exams.

Is it relevant that all your examples feature of the...  so you can include (what look to me like additional determiners) my and these in your examples?

@FumbleFingers - I understood your suggestion. The issue I face is in distributive determiner and pronoun as I found different answers.
. I think others are also have the same doubt
This post also raised the same question without a definite answer (comments in answer)
I have a similar question. Why "one" is determiner in the first sentence and pronoun in the second? 1.One of my friends lives in Brighton. 2.It's a present for one of my children. (From OALD, "one" entry)
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176561/is-neithr-pronoun-or-determiner

I found this: Distributive determiners include words such as 'each', 'every', 'all', 'half', 'either', 'neither', 'only', 'both' and so on. According to the Collins Dictionary, a distributive is defined as those words “referring separately to the individual people or items in a group, as the words each and every”. One of their "five examples of sentences using distributive determiners" at the end of the page is Only one per group is allowed to participate in the discussion. (Which to me implies one is one of them! :)


[1] [Each of my teachers] has long hair.
[2] [Both of my close friends] live in Delhi.
[3] [Either of these plans] sounds good.
[4] [Neither of these videos] explains the procedure in detail.

All the items in your examples are determinatives in partitive 'fused determiner-head' noun phrases. "Each" and "every" are distributive, while "either" and "neither" are disjunctive.
They are called 'fused' because the head element is combined (or fused), with a dependent item, namely a determiner in your examples.
[2] for example means both members of the set of my close friends live in Delhi.

I am unaware of the term determinatives.
As per Wikipedia - All are pronouns   -

Each went his own way (each used as a pronoun, without an accompanying noun)
Each man went his own way (each used as a determiner, accompanying the noun man)
Each of the answers is correct (each used as a pronoun, with an accompanying prepositional phrase of the answers)
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_pronoun


@JamesMathai Determinative is the word class (part of speech) and determiner is its function. Note the slightly different spellings. Wiki is wrong about this. Here's a link to an excellent grammar textbook link         Look at p134 'The Partitive Type', which explains everything

The link you sent could not be accessed.
This post also raised the same question without a definite answer (comments in answer)
I have a similar question. Why "one" is determiner in the first sentence and pronoun in the second? 1.One of my friends lives in Brighton. 2.It's a present for one of my children. (From OALD, "one" entry)
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176561/is-neithr-pronoun-or-determiner

@JamesMathai In the link at top right, click "English" and it will open. It may take a short while to open.

Thank you. The terms used are different. I shall go through it.

The link given below has explanation for examples in the OP

I. Both as a Pre-determiner..
When 'both' is used before a determiner (as a pre-determiner), we can use it with or without the preposition 'of'. Look at the examples:
1.I loved both my children. = I loved both of my children.
2.Both the restaurants serve delicious food. = Both of the restaurants serve delicious food.


II.Neither Followed by 'Of'.
'Neither' can be followed by the preposition 'of'. In this case, a partitive structure is formed. Pay attention to the examples:
1.Neither of the restaurants served good food. (with plural noun and article)
2.. Neither of my friends knew how to cook. (with plural noun and possessive pronoun)


III. Either Followed by 'Of'.
When using an object pronoun or a plural noun with a determiner, we must use the construction 'either of' to refer to one of two options. For example:
1.Either of the restaurants served good food. (with plural noun and article)
2.I didn't like either of these books. (with plural noun and demonstrative pronoun)


IV. All as a Pre-determiner..
When using a noun with a determiner, we can use 'all' or 'all of'. However, when using a pronoun, only 'all of' is allowed. For example:
1.All the children are playing and dancing. = All of the children are playing and dancing.


V. Each as a Pre-determiner..
'Each' is used to refer to all individuals or items within a group when there are three or more things or people. It is typically used with singular nouns to emphasize the individuality of each item or person.
For example:
1.I told each of my parents individually. (noun with a possessive pronoun)
Ref. https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/689/distributives

